# QMediaPlayer negative playbackRate doesn't rewind video

Tags: python, pyqt5, qmediaplayer

I am trying to use `QMediaPlayer` to create a.. media player. I want to have an ability to rewind videos on press of a button.

But setting a negative `playbackRate` via `QMediaPlayer.setPlaybackRate` doesn't seem to put video on rewind. It just keeps playing forward.

I **don't want** to change the **position** of the video, I want the video to *play at negative speed*. Through some logic of mine, setting `playbackRate` to a negative value would make the video **play in reverse**. But that just doesn't happen. If you can't understand me clearly, here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBnI-oH0YtI&t=49s) of what the playback should look like.

Here is some barebones code to reproduce the problem:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

class VideoWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(videoWidget)

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
            QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(r"<some video file>.mp4"))
        )
        self.mediaPlayer.play()

        app.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            key = event.key()

            if key == Qt.Key_A:
                self.mediaPlayer.setPlaybackRate(1.0)
            elif key == Qt.Key_Y:
                self.mediaPlayer.setPlaybackRate(-1.0) # This doesn't work! :(

        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    player = VideoWindow()
    player.resize(640, 480)
    player.show()

    exitCode = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(exitCode)
```

I tried searching for a solution, but I got nothing more than what [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#playbackRate-prop) says (emphasis mine):

> Values **less than zero** can be set and indicate the **media will rewind** at
>   the multiplier of the standard pace.

However, I am not seeing this effect.

I did notice this:

> Not all playback services support change of the playback rate.

Is it possible that I can't rewind an mp4? Perhaps I need to install / change something?

Comment: to me it works correctly in Linux with PyQt5 5.11.2, what is your OS and your version of PyQt5?

Comment: please see https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/multimediawidgets/player.py

Comment: @eyllanesc I have Windows 10 (1803 I believe, if relevant) and the same version of PyQt.

Comment: @S.Nick I tried the example, and added `self.rateBox.addItem("-2.0x", -2.0)`, but choosing it doesn't rewind the video. It just keeps playing with last positive speed it was set to, just like in my code.

Comment: @eyllanesc Do you have any idea why it would work in Linux but not Windows? Could I be missing a program / package / setting / anything?

Comment: @BožoStojković I think the backend does not support it, report it as a bug

Comment: I had the same problem in the past and I solved make a custom method https://github.com/All4Gis/QGISFMV/blob/master/code/player/QgsFmvPlayer.py#L608

Comment: @eyllanesc I opened up a [thread on Riverbank mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2018-September/040859.html)

Comment: @FranciscoRaga Do you mean the `rewindMedia` method? If yes, that's not what I am looking for. Please read [my comment on S. Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155722/qmediaplayer-negative-playbackrate-doesnt-rewind-video/52264919#comment91544583_52264919)

Answer (score 3):

`QMediaPlayer.playbackRate` property holds the *playback rate* of the current media.
This value is a multiplier applied to the media's standard play rate.

Press the `Key_A`, `Key_Z`, `Key_Y` keys to see how it works.

---

If you want to rewind the video, you should use `QMediaPlayer.position` property, which holds the *playback position* of the current media.
The value is the current playback position, expressed in milliseconds since the beginning of the media.

Press the `Key_M`, `Key_P` keys to see how it works.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

class VideoWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(videoWidget)

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
            QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(r"<some video file>.mp4"))
        )
        self.mediaPlayer.play()

        app.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            key = event.key()

            # It Playback Rate !
            if key == Qt.Key_A:
                #self.mediaPlayer.setPlaybackRate(1.0)
                self.mediaPlayer.setPlaybackRate(1.5)
            elif key == Qt.Key_Z:
                self.mediaPlayer.setPlaybackRate(0.8)
            elif key == Qt.Key_Y:
                self.mediaPlayer.setPlaybackRate(1.0)                        

            # setPosition(int), argument is in milliseconds.
            elif key == Qt.Key_M:
                self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(self.mediaPlayer.position() - 10000)
            elif key == Qt.Key_P:
                self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(self.mediaPlayer.position() + 10000)                

        return super().eventFilter(source, event)


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    player = VideoWindow()
    player.resize(640, 480)
    player.show()

    exitCode = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(exitCode)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I wanted. I don't want to change position of the video, I want the video to _play_ at negative speed. Through some logic of mine, setting `playbackRate` to negative number would make the video **play in reverse**. But that just doesn't happen. If you can't understand me clearly, here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBnI-oH0YtI&t=49s) of what should happen to my videos.